# Iterating through collections

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have a collection that I'm attempting to iterate through, which I am able to do no problem. What I would like to achieve is seeing the next object in the collection, but I am unable to find anything on this.

I've tried to look ahead using a (+ 1) in the if statement, but this doesn't seem to work.

```vb
For each a in CollBlank
   if CollBlank(a + 1) <> "some value" then
        'do code
   end if
Next
```

Ideally, I'd like to be able to look ahead.

Access-vba & excel-vba are tagged since collections are used in both access and excel, I'm personally using it in Access right now, but most tutorials are through Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using `for each`, use a `for` loop with an index variable, for example:

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 to CollBlank.Count - 2
    If CollBlank(i + 1) <> "some value" Then
        ' Do stuff
    End If
Next i
```